# Is it possible to blend from two textures based on XYZ coordinates of object?

Tags: texturing, materials

Quick texture/materials question.

I know you can set up a ColorRamp to respond to XYZ coordinates - for instance, I can create a ColorRamp that blends from blue to red and control it with XYZ, so however higher or lower the object is on the Z axis the color changes.

I am curious how I could do something like this with two separate textures. For instance, having a waterfall blend from a material like sand to a water-node setup.

Comment: I am guessing I use a coordinates node on a mix shader's "FACTOR" input, just not sure how to make the object respond appropriately

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty much the same as your blue/red example, except instead of blue and red use black and white in the colorramp and then that output goes into the fac input of either a mixrgb node to mix two texture colors (the two texture color outputs go into the two color inputs), or the fac of a mix shader mixing two shaders.